# How to get the path of loaded files

Tags: ruby, path, require

How can I check the path from where required files are loaded? For example, how can I check from which path the files `set.rb` and `abc/pqr.rb` are loaded in the following script?

```
require 'set'
require 'abc/pqr'
```

Comment: Please give more details on what you want exactly to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the last element of the array `$LOADED_FEATURES` right after a file load succeeds.

```
...
require 'set'
$LOADED_FEATURES.last # => gives the path for `set` if it was loaded properly
...
require 'abc/pqr'
$LOADED_FEATURES.last # => gives the path for `abd/pqr` if it was loaded properly
...
```

If you need to do it later, then you need to search the appropriate path from the `$LOADED_FEATURES` using some kind of string match.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea $LOADED_FEATURES existed.  Really nice sawa!